# How to check if a user has enough rights to create symlinks in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, symlink, access-rights

Creating symbolic links in Windows is restricted. Usually, administrator have enough rights to do so, but users haven't.

- How can I check if the current user has enough rights to use `New-Symlink` in PowerShell?
- Is there any better work-around then using `cp` to solve the problem, if `New-Symlink` is not available?

---

A set of scripts pre-compile several simulation libraries into directories named after the vendor tool. I'm using symlinks to switch and map the chosen vendor library to a generic folder name. Otherwise I need to pre-compile the library on every library change, which takes > 5 minutes and creates ~2 GiB data.

Comment: Why not put the `New-Symlink` commannd in a `try/catch` block ?

Comment: Is this considered "good style"? In Python yes, but in PowerShell?

Comment: https://userrights.codeplex.com/ and check for SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege right. Might be overkill, though, if that's the only thing you want to do ... You can also use: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've no better advice to give you than use `try/catch`:

```
try {
    New-Symlink -...
    "Symlink created successfully"
} catch {
    Write-Warning "Could not create symlink"
    #workaround
}
```

You can even differentiate exception types, see [about_Try_Catch_Finally](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847793.aspx) and some examples here too [An Introduction to Error Handling in PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/)

Sidenote:

I guess you use the [cmdlet from TechNet gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-SymLink-60d2531e) ? If you do, the last update apparently **removed Admin requirement** (see script description on TechNet).

Comment: As far as I can see, I have two `New-Symlink` CmdLets ... It's a bit strange: One is defined in Pscx (3.2.1.0), which is automatically loaded by $PROFILE. I can also see it in ISE, but regarding the help-page of it, it says it's a Pscx CmdLet. So no, my CmdLet is not from TechNet :)

Comment: Maybe you should try the other one then ? ;-)